# Issue with HTTP Request with Patch method in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, patch

Following is my code:

```
  $http({
      url: 'https://apistage.dealsignal.com/api/v0/company_watchlists/' + wishlist_id,
      method: 'PATCH',
      params: {
          list: {
              add_company_ids: ['61737'],
              name: 'My Wishlist'
          },
          api_key: 'CtxY3Kpc7ZDL8VDfLmPt9wss'
      }
  })
      .success(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
      }).
  error(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      return false;
  });
```

I am getting bad request error but same request with patch method is working in REST CLIENT on chrome.

Comment: Most of the time when a request fails from the browser, but succeeds in a Postman or another REST client, it means that CORS in the server is not set correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Please see the [Angular Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#patch). This will be Data not params.

```
$http({
  url: 'https://apistage.dealsignal.com/api/v0/company_watchlists/' + wishlist_id,
  method: 'PATCH',
  data: {
      list: {
          add_company_ids: ['61737'],
          name: 'My Wishlist'
      },
      api_key: 'CtxY3Kpc7ZDL8VDfLmPt9wss'
  }
}).success(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
  }).
  error(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I am trying to utilize this answer, but my back-end doesn't receive anything from the data parameter. Any ideas? Originally I tried using $resource, but have the same issue. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917898/asp-net-odata-patchvalue-received-from-angular-is-nothing)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about it, but may be the problem is that the parameter "params" should be named "data", as when you make a POST request.

Hope it helps.